# Remove a specific xmlns from root element of xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to make a transformation for an XML document but i cannot find a solution since i do not know XSLT.
I have the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses xmlns="http://www.test.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://whatever/test.xsd'>

  <address>
    <name>Joe Tester</name>
    <street>Baker street 5</street>
  </address>

</addresses>
```

and I want to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addresses xmlns="http://www.test.org/xml">

  <address>
    <name>Joe Tester</name>
    <street>Baker street 5</street>
  </address>

</addresses>
```

(Consider that xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="..." has already excluded using another XSLT before this one).

Can someone help me find a solution?

The XSLT used to eliminate the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How about cribbing off of the 'other XSLT' indicated in your post to eliminate the bad attribute?

Comment: @hd1 - The remaining part user466825 wants to omit is a namespace declaration, not an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"
>

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the xmlns:xsi=".." is not removed.

Comment: You're right.  Ian Roberts' solution was one step closer than mine, but it looks like he still had one oversight.  Please try the modified approach above.

Answer (score 4):

I have got two options:

XSLT1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name(.)='noNamespaceSchemaLocation']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<addresses xmlns="http://www.test.org/xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <address>
    <name>Joe Tester</name>
    <street>Baker street 5</street>
  </address>
</addresses>
```

XSLT2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name(.)='noNamespaceSchemaLocation']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<addresses>
  <address>
    <name>Joe Tester</name>
    <street>Baker street 5</street>
  </address>
</addresses>
```

Comment: My need is to remove the xmlns:xsi=".." from the root element without removing the xmlns, or any other xmlns:* .

Comment: Namespace declaration, unlike any other attribute won't be treated normally! You may not want the declaration to be there in output XML but, XSLT parser thinks it is needed (because it is possible that you might have used the namespace as prefix to some element in your XML!)

Comment: so you either have to get rid of xmlns from your whole XML or get rid of just one element/attribute (or multiple) which are using that namespace prefix!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when copying an element node `<xsl:copy>` implicitly copies namespace nodes that are in scope at that point in the document. Try adding an extra template for element nodes to specifically exclude the `xsi` namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name() = 'xsi')]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If your `xsl:stylesheet` has an `xmlns:xsi` then you may also find you need to add `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14188547/592139).

This should prevent the xsi namespace from appearing in the output if it is there *solely* because it was copied from the input, though the serialiser may re-introduce it if required to make the output well formed (i.e. if it needs to output an element or attribute in that namespace).

Comment: This almost worked, but it seems that it doesn't work because `self::xsi` is a node test for an _element_ named xsi.  `not(name() = 'xsi')` or `not(. = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')` should do the job though.

Comment: I think you need a template to drop `@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` .. otherwise the value shows up in output as orphan, because you are using `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>`

Comment: @InfantProgrammer'Aravind' OP said they'd already removed that in another stylesheet.

Comment: Agreed but May be he has misinterpreted ! observing the input and desired output XML samples, it looks like OP wants to get rid of namespace declaratoin using XSLT! Also the same thing he has commented on other answers as well.

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' yes, and my point is that removing all _uses_ of the namespace is not sufficient to achieve this, because `<xsl:copy>` copies namespace nodes (i.e. in-scope declarations from the source XML) along with the element it is copying.  XSLT 2.0 allows `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">` but that isn't an option in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: so no hope in XSLT 1.0! tried to manually copy elements instead of `<xsl:copy>` .. it removes base namespace declaration itself!

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' have you actually tried my solution (or the variant of it that is part of [JLRishe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14188547/592139))?  You can't use `<xsl:copy>` but you can achieve the desired effect using `<xsl:element>`.

Comment: yup but no hope! that gives same result as of my `XSLT1` code! .. `XSLT2` on the other hand totally gets rid of whole namespace thing! which isn't desired as well.. I am puzzled to achieve the requirement here! OP wants this output: 
`<addresses xmlns="http://www.test.org/xml">`