# XSLT transformation : Transfer only 1 of the namespaces

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I am new to XSLT transformation and cant seem to get the following result

I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03 pain.002.001.03.xsd">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
```

need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
```

Where the rest of the document should remain the same.

I have put together the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation">
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not going to work, because `"Prefixed namespace bindings may not be empty"` (quoting the error message you'll get, if you try).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a specific xmlns from root element of xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188119/remove-a-specific-xmlns-from-root-element-of-xml)